# How to create a loop over different datasets?

Tags: r, loops

i need your help. I want to run a code over different datasets. They are called dfQB, dfRB, dfOL, dfFB, dfWR, dfTE, dfST, dfDB, dfLB, dfDL and dfDE. I have this code. Is it possible to add a second loop that does this code for every of the datasets mentioned above? Help is much appreciated!

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  ecdf_fun <- function(x,perc) ecdf(x)(perc)
  de=df[i,5:10]
  a=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Forty,de[1]))
  b=(ecdf_fun(df$Vertical,de[2]))
  c=(ecdf_fun(df$BenchReps,de[3]))
  d=(ecdf_fun(df$BroadJump,de[4]))
  e=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Cone,de[5]))
  f=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Shuttle,de[6]))
  nenner=6-sum(is.na(a), is.na(b),is.na(c), is.na(d),is.na(e), is.na(f))
  if (is.na(a)) {a <- 0}
  if (is.na(b)) {b <- 0}
  if (is.na(c)) {c <- 0}
  if (is.na(d)) {d <- 0}
  if (is.na(e)) {e <- 0}
  if (is.na(f)) {f <- 0}
  df$RAS[i]=((a+b+c+d+e+f)/nenner)*10
}
```

Getting the appropriate help!

Comment: Is `df` a generic name for each of your data.frames?

Comment: Well df is the whole dataset, but i just used it as an example in here. The dataframes the code shall run over are "dfQB, dfRB, dfOL, dfFB, dfWR, dfTE, dfST, dfDB, dfLB, dfDL and dfDE"

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, avoid maintaining many similarly structured data frames as separate objects in your global environment. Instead, [store such similar data frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451). From there, you can run `lapply` on the list to uniformly apply on any defined or  user defined method.

```r
# NAMED LIST OF DFS
fb_position_dfs <- list(
   QB=dfQB, RB=dfRB, OL=dfOL, FB=dfFB, WR=dfWR, TE=dfTE, 
   ST=dfST, DB=dfDB, LB=dfLB, DL=dfDL, DE=dfDE
)

# REMOVE SEPARATE OBJECTS
rm(dfQB, dfRB, dfOL, dfFB, dfWR, dfTE, dfST, dfDB, dfLB, dfDL, dfDE)

# USER-DEFINED METHOD
df_proc <- function(df) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ 
    ecdf_fun <- function(x,perc) ecdf(x)(perc) 
    de=df[i,5:10] 
    a=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Forty,de[1]))
    b=(ecdf_fun(df$Vertical,de[2]))
    c=(ecdf_fun(df$BenchReps,de[3])) 
    d=(ecdf_fun(df$BroadJump,de[4])) 
    e=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Cone,de[5])) 
    f=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Shuttle,de[6]))
    nenner=6-sum(is.na(a), is.na(b),is.na(c), is.na(d),is.na(e), is.na(f)) 

    if (is.na(a)) {a <- 0}
    if (is.na(b)) {b <- 0} 
    if (is.na(c)) {c <- 0} 
    if (is.na(d)) {d <- 0} 
    if (is.na(e)) {e <- 0} 
    if (is.na(f)) {f <- 0} 
 
    df$RAS[i]=((a+b+c+d+e+f)/nenner)*10 
  }
  return(df)
}

# ITERATE THROUGH DFS APPLYING METHOD
new_fb_position_dfs <- lapply(fb_position_dfs, df_proc)
```

If by chance the data frames originating from a master data frame split by position, use `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) to apply user-define method on the splits:

```r
# ITERATE THROUGH SPLITS OF DF AND APPLY METHOD
new_fb_position_dfs <- by(fb_master_df, fb_master_df$position, df_proc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data.frames in a list and use `purrr::map` to iterate over each element.

```r
# install.packages("purrr")

library(purrr)

datasets <- list(
  dfQB,
  dfRB,
  dfOL,
  dfFB,
  dfWR,
  dfTE,
  dfST,
  dfDB,
  dfLB,
  dfDL,
  dfDE
)

# `map` returns a list with the result of calling the function (second argument)
# with each element of the first argument (`datasets`).
datasets_transformed <- map(
  datasets,
  \(df) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      ecdf_fun <- function(x,perc) ecdf(x)(perc)
      de=df[i,5:10]
      a=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Forty,de[1]))
      b=(ecdf_fun(df$Vertical,de[2]))
      c=(ecdf_fun(df$BenchReps,de[3]))
      d=(ecdf_fun(df$BroadJump,de[4]))
      e=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Cone,de[5]))
      f=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Shuttle,de[6]))
      nenner=6-sum(is.na(a), is.na(b),is.na(c), is.na(d),is.na(e), is.na(f))
      if (is.na(a)) {a <- 0}
      if (is.na(b)) {b <- 0}
      if (is.na(c)) {c <- 0}
      if (is.na(d)) {d <- 0}
      if (is.na(e)) {e <- 0}
      if (is.na(f)) {f <- 0}
      df$RAS[i]=((a+b+c+d+e+f)/nenner)*10
    }
    
    df
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to assign the data frames to a list, another approach is to simply list the data frame names in a vector, and use `get()` within an `lapply()` function to access the object from the parent environment.

Absent a minimal reproducible example, code to do this looks like the following:

```
dfList <- c("dfQB","dfRB","dfOL") # a subset of the data frames

updatedData <- lapply(dfList,function(x){
     df <- get(x) # get the actual data from parent environment 
     for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
          ecdf_fun <- function(x,perc) ecdf(x)(perc)
          de=df[i,5:10]
          a=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Forty,de[1]))
          b=(ecdf_fun(df$Vertical,de[2]))
          c=(ecdf_fun(df$BenchReps,de[3]))
          d=(ecdf_fun(df$BroadJump,de[4]))
          e=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Cone,de[5]))
          f=(1-ecdf_fun(df$Shuttle,de[6]))
          nenner=6-sum(is.na(a), is.na(b),is.na(c), is.na(d),is.na(e), is.na(f))
          if (is.na(a)) {a <- 0}
          if (is.na(b)) {b <- 0}
          if (is.na(c)) {c <- 0}
          if (is.na(d)) {d <- 0}
          if (is.na(e)) {e <- 0}
          if (is.na(f)) {f <- 0}
          df$RAS[i]=((a+b+c+d+e+f)/nenner)*10
     }
     df # return to parent environment 
})
```

At this point, the object `updatedData` is a list of data frames.

As minimal reproducible example we'll download and update one column from the nine generations of Pokémon stats.

First, we'll download the data and unzip it to a subdirectory of the current working directory.

```
   download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/PokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
   unzip("pokemonData.zip",exdir="./pokemonData")
```

Next, we'll create a vector containing the .csv files we downloaded.

```
thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",pattern = ".csv",
                              full.names=TRUE)
```

Next, we use the vector of file names to read the data into data frames and assign them as data frames in the global environment via the `assign()` function. Yes, I am aware that it's [easier to work with the data frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames), but this replicates the "current state" of the original post.

```
pokemonDataFiles <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     df <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     dfName <- substr(x,15,19)
     assign(dfName,df,envir = .GlobalEnv) # assign to global environment 
})
```

Next, we'll create a vector to represent the names of the data frames we created.

Finally, we multiply the `HP` stat by ten in each data frame, return the data frame to a list, and compare the original and updated data for one data frame.

```
theNames <- paste0("gen0",1:9)
updatedData <- lapply(theNames,function(df){
     x <- get(df)
     x$HP <- x$HP * 10 
     x
})
# compare the first few rows of gen01 Pokemon HP
head(data.frame(original.HP = gen01$HP,updatedHP =updatedData[[1]][["HP"]]))
```

...and the output:

```
> head(data.frame(original.HP = gen01$HP,updatedHP = updatedData[[1]][["HP"]]))
  original.HP updatedHP
1          45       450
2          60       600
3          80       800
4          39       390
5          58       580
6          78       780
```